# Will IDE hard drive work if i select AHCI in BIOS?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, ide, ahci

I have a Windows 7 installation on an old hdd that i am still using today.
I want to jump on Windows 10, but because i do not want to format my old disc, i bought a new SSD disk.

I saw that since it is an ssd, it is better to select AHCI on the BIOS settings (now it is IDE).
So if i select AHCI, and install Windows 10 on the SSD, will the old IDE hard disk be readable by my new Windows 10 installation?

Answer (score 2):

It is suggested to enable ahci in Windows 7 Before you switch the bios setting, here is how.

Changing from IDE to AHCI

In regedit navigate to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Msahci,

click "Start" in the right pane and modify value to 0

Do the same for

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\IastorV

Changing from RAID to AHCI, you need one more step.

Msahci driver requires Atapi.sys miniport to be loaded during boot as well. So you need to change theStart value to 0 for both of the following entries in your registry. You can use regedit.exe utility.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\msahci

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\atapi

Restart the PC, enter the bios and enable AHCI, save changes on exit, boot into Windows, it will install necessary drivers.

Restart PC again

Done.

Now you can install the new SSD and W10, then if you want to boot off the old W7 drive it will work also.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/changing-from-raid-to-ahci/4c94f678-6bd1-48a6-b871-8872c841023a?page=2&auth=1) You may have to log in or create account to see the  Microsoft source page.